# My First Python Web App

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a program by running Django using manage.py runserver ip:port in my Linux box as a non-root user. My first objective is that if a user enters a URL in the browser http://ip:port it should display something or a welcome content.

So I modified my mysite/url.py something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('', ''),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

python manage.py runserver : runs and start fine but in browser I get below exception:

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: Empty URL pattern view name not permitted (for pattern '')

So how can construct the URL just like:

```
www.google.com
www.mail.yahoo.com
www.mysite.com
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know what the second tuple element means, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty pattern will match anything, so you should be anchoring it to full empty string. The second tuple parameter must also be a view name.

In your URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'views.home'),     # ^$ means, beginning of string followed by end of string, in other words match on exactly empty string and nothing else
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In a `views.py` in the same directory:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

Comment: @Prakash Wow. I totally misunderstood that question.

Comment: @Edwin: The question was ambiguous and your answer was completely valid (and I gave it a +1). I just answered the question by looking at the issues with the URLconf and I guess it happened to be what the OP wanted :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're willing to get down to the nitty-gritty and configure, run, and host your own Apache Server (or another server config) **AND** register a domain name, you **CANNOT** change the domain name from within Python/Django.

Django only handles everything that comes after the domain name, such as the `/home/` portion of the URL `http://www.mysite.com/home/`.

If you're up to it, the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) has a pretty good [section on deploying Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/) and setting up the server to run it, but it doesn't cover all the bases.